# Calculate summation of numbers

Tags: python

I'm a new python programmer and I want to calculate the sum of H for i from zero to 5 and finally calculate the sum of each of them. The code I wrote is like this, can anyone help me?

```
i=0
he=float(input("he:"))
while i<6 :
    summation=0
    H1=100-((2*i*1500)-he)
    H2=120+((2*i*1200)-he)
    H3=200-((2*i*1100)+he)
    H4=80+((2*i*1100)+he)
    summation+=(H1+H2+H3+H4)
    i+=1
    print(summation)
```

Comment: instantiate summation = 0 before the while loop. Also i = 0 if you haven't done that

Comment: Let's provide some sample inputs - what's *H*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this.

```
he = float(input("he:"))
summation = 0
for i in range(6):
    H1 = 100 - ((2 * i * 1500) - he)
    H2 = 120 + ((2 * i * 1200) - he)
    H3 = 200 - ((2 * i * 1100) + he)
    H4 =  80 + ((2 * i * 1100) + he)
    summation += H1 + H2 + H3 + H4
    print(f"summation at step {i}: {summation}")
```